# Insertar datos en una tabla en otra seleccionando dinámicamente los datos según el filtro

Tags: sql, update

Tengo la tabla colores en la que por un error de un procedimiento se han generado duplicados, lo que ha generado que en la tabla vehículos se hayan introducido registros con códigos de color erróneos, usando dichos duplicados.

Además, la tabla de colores va con una clave por cliente aparte de la clave VCB_KEY. Os pongo unas filas:

| VCB_KEY | CLI_KEY | COD_CLR | COL_NOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Rojo |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Azul |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | Red |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | Blue |

En este caso para el CLI_KEY 1 y el COL_NOM Rojo se han duplicado filas con COD_CLR 64, 71, 86, etc.

La tabla colores tiene este dataset:
VCB_KEY int auto_increment primary key,
CLI_KEY int not null,
COD_CLR varchar(8)  not null,
COL_NOM varchar(64) not null,

Además tiene una constraint:
constraint UQ_VEH_COL unique (CLI_KEY, COD_CLR),

Y una foreign key de CLI_KEY hacia la tabla clientes, que no viene al caso.

Antes de borrar estas filas necesito actualizar la tabla vehículos con los colores correctos, es decir, donde están esos 64, 71, 86, etc. poner el 1, y así con todos los colores correctos para cada cliente. He visto en la versión en inglés de esta página ejemplos de algo llamado "correlated update" pero no he sido capaz de hacerlo funcionar. Después he ido a hacer una consulta de actualización buscando el mínimo de los códigos, es decir, buscando por CLI_KEY y COL_NOM de cada fila "n" de la tabla VEHICULOS, saca el mínimo de los VCB_KEY de la tabla COLORES para después actualizar la fila "n":

```
update VEHICULO v
set v.VCB_KEY = minimo.minKey
from VEHICULO v
inner join (select min(c.VCB_KEY) minKey, c.CLI_KEY
        from VEHICULO v, COLORES c
        where v.VCB_KEY = c.VCB_KEY
        group by c.VCB_NOM, c.CLI_KEY) minimo
on v.CLI_KEY = minimo.CLI_KEY
and v.VCB_KEY = minimo.VCB_KEY
```

Espero haberme explicado. ¿Podrían ayudarme? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cual Es tu DBMS? Las preguntas de SQL requieren una etiqueta del DBMS, para que sabemos que sintaxis tu DBMS permite. Además, estás mostrando una consulta de actualización, pero olvidaste de explicar si funciona o no,  y si no, que problema ocurre. ¿Acepta tu DBMS esa sintaxis? ¿O produce un error? Si hay un mensaje de error, ¿cuál es?

Comment: El error que da al ejecutar el código que he expuesto es: 
`[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from VEHICULO v inner join (select min(c.VCB_KEY) minKey from VEHI' at line 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olvidaste de mencionar tu DBMS. La consulta de actualización que estas mostrando tiene una sintaxis que no es válido en cada DBMS.

Bueno, tu tabla VEHICULO contiene filas con un VCB_KEY que no es lo mínimo para la combinación de CLI_KEY y COL_NOM. Estas filas hay que corregir.

Así que no sé cual DBMS usas, no puedo ofrecer una solución perfecta, porque no sé que sintaxis permite tu DBMS. La próxima consulta de actualización es lo más básica posible y debe funcionar en cada DBMS.

```
update vehiculo
set vcb_key =
(
  select min(mejor.vcb_key)
  from colores actual
  join colores mejor on mejor.cli_key = actual.cli_key
                    and mejor.col_nom = actual.col_nom
  where actual.vcb_key = vehiculo.vcb_key
);
```

Después puedes eliminar los duplicados de tu tabla COLORES:

```
delete from colores
where exists
(
  select null
  from colores mejor
  where mejor.cli_key = colores.cli_key
    and mejor.col_nom = colores.col_nom
    and mejor.vcb_key < colores.vcb_key
);
```

(Si estas usando MySQL, puede ser necesario cambiar `from colores mejor` a `from (select * from colores) mejor`, porque hay una limitación ridícula en MySQL que prohíbe usar la misma tabla del UPDATE o DELETE directamente en una subconsulta.)

Y por fin puedes crear una restricción única para la llave natural de la tabla COLORES (CLI_KEY, COL_NOM) para evitar de tener duplicados nuevos en el futuro.

```
alter table colores add constraint colores_unique unique (cli_key, col_nom);
```

Comment: Hola, ¿esta consulta no pondrá a todos los vehículos el mismo vcb_key?

Comment: Todos los vehiculos reciben el minimo vcb_key para su cli_key y col_nom. Por ejemplo: En la tabla COLORES haya un duplicado: 1|1|1|Rojo (la fila de tu ejemplo) y 99|1|1|Rojo - entonces hay dos filas del mismo cliente cli_key 1 y mismo color Rojo. Y en la tabla VEHICULOS haya filas con vcb_key 1 y filas con vcb_key 99. Despues de la consulta de actualización, todos las filas en la tabla VEHICULOS que tenían vcb_key 1 todavía tendrán vcb_key 1, pero las filas que tenían vcb_key 99 también tendrán vcb_key 1, porque vcb_key 99 es un duplicado de vcb_key 1.

Comment: Entonces, no, no es que todos los vehículos tendrán el mismo vcb_key. Pero todos los vehículos del mismo cliente y color tendrán el mismo vcb_key.

Comment: Despues de esta acción puedes eliminar los duplicados de la tabla COLORES. Entonces te aconsejo crear una restricción única para la llave natural COLORES(CLI_KEY, COL_NOM). para evitar de tener nuevos duplicados en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he ejecutado el update, no ha dado error, he hecho commit y al consultar la tabla VEHICULOS sigue devolviendo lo mismo que antes.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que la tabla VEHICULOS ya esta bien? Mencionaste duplicados en tu tabla COLORES. ¿Hay filas en la tabla VEHICULOS que tienen un VCB_KEY alto para un CLI_KEY+COL_NOM para que existe un VCB_KEY menos alta? Aquí puedes ver que funciona bien: https://dbfiddle.uk/Qfft4LZ3

Comment: Gracias por tu dbfiddle, ya lo tengo funcionando. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Te respondo en MySQL porque la dificultad no la has encontrado en el SQL, sino en la estructura de tu base de datos y de las consultas. Si utilizas cualquier otro sistema gestor, sólo tendrás que adaptar algunas instrucciones, pero la idea será la misma.

En primer lugar, lo que te ha pasado ha sido a consecuencia de no haber normalizado tu tabla `VEHICULO`. Los colores deberían haber estado en otra tabla y en `VEHICULO` únicamente debería haber estado `COD_CLR`. Pero eso ya lo arreglaremos, empecemos reproduciendo el fallo que comentas con este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICULO(
  VCB_KEY int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  CLI_KEY int,
  COD_CLR int,
  COL_NOM varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO VEHICULO (CLI_KEY, COD_CLR, COL_NOM) VALUES
  ('1','1','Rojo'),
  ('1','2','Azul'),
  ('2','1','Red'),
  ('2','2','Blue'),
  ('1','64','Rojo'),
  ('1','71','Rojo'),
  ('1','86','Rojo');
```

Con la tabla `VEHICULO` con este aspecto:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| VCB_KEY | CLI_KEY | COD_CLR | COL_NOM |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
|       2 |       1 |       2 | Azul    |
|       3 |       2 |       1 | Red     |
|       4 |       2 |       2 | Blue    |
|       5 |       1 |      64 | Rojo    |
|       6 |       1 |      71 | Rojo    |
|       7 |       1 |      86 | Rojo    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

El primer paso serán unificar esos duplicados en los `COD_CLR`:

```
UPDATE VEHICULO v JOIN (
    SELECT COL_NOM,
      MIN(COD_CLR) COD_CLR
      FROM VEHICULO
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(COL_NOM)
  SET v.COD_CLR=c1.COD_CLR;
```

Obteniendo este resultado:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| VCB_KEY | CLI_KEY | COD_CLR | COL_NOM |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
|       2 |       1 |       2 | Azul    |
|       3 |       2 |       1 | Red     |
|       4 |       2 |       2 | Blue    |
|       5 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
|       6 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
|       7 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Asegurándonos de que cada cliente no pueda tener más de un vehículo con el mismo color. Entonces, y sólo entonces, podremos eliminar los duplicados así:

```
DELETE FROM VEHICULO
  WHERE VCB_KEY NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(VCB_KEY) VCB_KEY
      FROM VEHICULO
      GROUP BY CLI_KEY,COD_CLR
  );
```

Obteniendo:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| VCB_KEY | CLI_KEY | COD_CLR | COL_NOM |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
|       2 |       1 |       2 | Azul    |
|       3 |       2 |       1 | Red     |
|       4 |       2 |       2 | Blue    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Que entiendo que fuera lo que esperabas. Porque es lo que parece que intentabas hacer con tu consulta en un único paso.

Si esto ahora está bien, vayamos con la normalización para evitar fallos similares en el futuro. Para ello, creamos la tabla `COLOR` de forma que no vuelvan a aparecer duplicados ni nombres en inglés:

```
CREATE TABLE COLOR
SELECT COD_CLR,COL_NOM
  FROM VEHICULO
  JOIN (
    SELECT COD_CLR,
      MIN(VCB_KEY) VCB_KEY
      FROM VEHICULO
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(COD_CLR,VCB_KEY);
```

Y ahora eliminamos la redundancia en la tabla `VEHICULO` y creamos una clave ajena para que dejes de inventarte colores duplicados:

```
ALTER TABLE COLOR
  ADD PRIMARY KEY(COD_CLR);

ALTER TABLE VEHICULO
  DROP COL_NOM,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(COD_CLR) REFERENCES COLOR(COD_CLR);
```

La tabla `VEHICULO` ahora tendrá este aspecto:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| VCB_KEY | CLI_KEY | COD_CLR |
+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |       2 |
|       3 |       2 |       1 |
|       4 |       2 |       2 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Pero podrás obtener los colores con una simple combinación:

```
SELECT * FROM VEHICULO
  JOIN COLOR USING(COD_CLR);
```

Obteniendo:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| COD_CLR | VCB_KEY | CLI_KEY | COL_NOM |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       1 | Rojo    |
|       2 |       2 |       1 | Azul    |
|       1 |       3 |       2 | Rojo    |
|       2 |       4 |       2 | Azul    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Sin duplicados y en español.

Espero haberte ayudado. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: No pienso que hay un problema de normalización. La tabla mostrada es la tabla COLORES. Por cliente (CLI_KEY) hay colores (COL_NOM). Esto es la llave natural. Los clientes usan códigos propios para sus colores, para los cuales hay una columna más: COD_CLR. Finalmente, la tabla tiene une columna adicional para una llave sustituta/artificial (VCB_KEY). El problema es que probablemente hay una restricción única para la llave sustituta (VCB_KEY), pero no para la llave natural (CLI_KEY + COL_NOM). Esto es un error bastante común en bases de data con llave sustitutas...

Comment: Entonces, el problema no es de normalización, sino de falta de restricciones que resulta en duplicados en la tabla. No sabemos casi nada de la tabla VEHICULO. Esa tabla tiene el VCB_KEY, que es la llave artificial de la tabla COLORES. Y esto es exactamente como debe ser en una base de data con llaves artificiales.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Según indica el OP, la tabla mostrada es la tabla `VEHICULO` en la que aparecen colores, la tabla `COLORES` ha sido creada por mí. ¿En qué te basas para pensar que los clientes usan códigos propios para sus colores? ¿Por qué, según tu criterio, un cliente no puede tener varios vehículos del mismo color?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu extenso mensaje, pero tu enfoque empieza mal porque creas la tabla vehículos con los colores, esa creación correspondería a la tabla colores. Creo que entonces no me expliqué bien en mi formulación de la pregunta.

Comment: @Corporativo Sí, por favor, aclárala un poco (con editar pregunta) y aporta el dataset en SQL para que podamos ayudarte, tal y como puedes ver en mi respuesta. ¿Cómo puede ser posible que tengas clientes en una tabla de colores en la que únicamente deberían los colores y sus códigos?

Comment: @DavidJP he agregado el dataset de la tabla COLORES, y sí, hay clientes en la tabla colores, cada cliente tiene sus propios nombres de colores, quizá para el que uno es rojo para otro es bermellón o granate.

Comment: @Corporativo Ok, el dataset es la estructura de la tabla y también los datos anómalos, para ver qué aspecto tienen (utiliza Ctrl+K para darle formato de código).  Entonces, para que me aclare, los colores tienen un código único, pero pueden recibir diferentes nombres dependiendo del cliente, ¿eso es lo que quieres modelar? ¿Y por qué no codificas los colores con su RGB o Pantone y así captas todas las tonalidades?

Comment: @DavidJP las codificaciones son así por exigencias funcionales, solo quiero arreglar lo que el procedimiento de importación ha estropeado.